# Sampling sorted vectors whose multiplication with a design matrix is also sorted

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix, random

I want to sample the elements of vectors a, b, c of length C in a way that both the elements of each vector a, b, c as well as the elements of D %*% A1 are sorted. Here, A1 is the matrix that results from row-binding the vectors a, b and c. D is a design matrix (see code).

I cannot use brute force until I find a solution because the real problem involves more than three vectors (a, b, c, d, ...) and potentially higher values of C. Therefore, brute force takes too long to find a solution.

**Minimal example:**

```
# Size of the vectors
C <- 3

# Sample sorted vectors
a <- sort(runif(C, 0, 1))
b <- sort(runif(C, 0, 1))
c <- sort(runif(C, 0, 1))

# Row-bind the vectors a, b, c to matrix A1
A1 <- rbind(a, b, c)

# Create a design matrix D
D <- matrix(c(1, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1), nrow = 3)

# Multiply
A2 <- D %*% A1

# Is the result as desired?
all(t(apply(A2, 1, sort)) == A2)
```

**General Example**

Code to create the 'larger cases' mentioned in the bounty.

```
# Size of the vectors
C <- 4

# Number of vectors
nvec <- 100

# Create matrix A1 with sorted rows
A1 <- vector("list", nvec)
for (i in 1:nvec) {
  A1[[i]] <- sort(runif(C, 0, 1))
}
A1 <- do.call(rbind, A1)

# Create a design matrix D
DPosition <- combn(nvec, 2)
D <- matrix(0, ncol(DPosition), nvec)
for (i in 1:nrow(D)) {
  D[i, DPosition[, i]] <- c(1, -1)
}

# Multiply
A2 <- D %*% A1

# Is the result as desired?
all(t(apply(A2, 1, sort)) == A2)
```

Do you have an idea how I could achieve this (in R)?

EDIT: Added a more general example to clarify how the problem scales.

Comment: you want the rows to be sorted on top of the columns?

Comment: I only want each row of A1 and A2 to be sorted. The columns do not matter.

Comment: I posted some code, but we might be able to give you a better answer if we understood the broader task.

Answer (score 4):

## Update

Here is an update for `f`, such that it returns a list with both `A1` and `D` with given `C` and `nr`, and `A2` is ***not negligibe***

```
f <- function(C, nr) {
  res <- matrix(nrow = nr, ncol = C)
  res[1, ] <- sort(runif(C, 1 - 1 / nr, 1))
  for (k in 2:nr) {
    d <- diff(res[k - 1, ])
    v <- c(runif(1, 0, d[1]), d)
    res[k, ] <- 1 - k / nr + cumsum(v - runif(1, 0, v[1]))
  }

  DPosition <- combn(nr, 2)
  D <- matrix(0, ncol(DPosition), nr)
  for (i in 1:nrow(D)) {
    D[i, DPosition[, i]] <- c(1, -1)
  }

  list(A1 = res, D = D)
}
```

for example

```
> C <- 4

> nr <- 6

> (r <- f(C, nr))
$A1
             [,1]         [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
[1,] 0.9074367087 0.9136961138 0.92941219 0.94173666
[2,] 0.6696354939 0.6726631943 0.68514756 0.69424033
[3,] 0.5017587194 0.5035297048 0.51475736 0.52259342
[4,] 0.3333633168 0.3347584666 0.34561028 0.35307051
[5,] 0.1669981771 0.1675170401 0.17749257 0.18407651
[6,] 0.0002043442 0.0006086951 0.01046971 0.01693914

$D
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    1   -1    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    1    0   -1    0    0    0
 [3,]    1    0    0   -1    0    0
 [4,]    1    0    0    0   -1    0
 [5,]    1    0    0    0    0   -1
 [6,]    0    1   -1    0    0    0
 [7,]    0    1    0   -1    0    0
 [8,]    0    1    0    0   -1    0
 [9,]    0    1    0    0    0   -1
[10,]    0    0    1   -1    0    0
[11,]    0    0    1    0   -1    0
[12,]    0    0    1    0    0   -1
[13,]    0    0    0    1   -1    0
[14,]    0    0    0    1    0   -1
[15,]    0    0    0    0    1   -1


> all(apply(r$A1, 1, Negate(is.unsorted)))
[1] TRUE

> (A2 <- with(r, D %*% A1))
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
 [1,] 0.2378012 0.2410329 0.2442646 0.2474963
 [2,] 0.4056780 0.4101664 0.4146548 0.4191432
 [3,] 0.5740734 0.5789376 0.5838019 0.5886662
 [4,] 0.7404385 0.7461791 0.7519196 0.7576602
 [5,] 0.9072324 0.9130874 0.9189425 0.9247975
 [6,] 0.1678768 0.1691335 0.1703902 0.1716469
 [7,] 0.3362722 0.3379047 0.3395373 0.3411698
 [8,] 0.5026373 0.5051462 0.5076550 0.5101638
 [9,] 0.6694311 0.6720545 0.6746778 0.6773012
[10,] 0.1683954 0.1687712 0.1691471 0.1695229
[11,] 0.3347605 0.3360127 0.3372648 0.3385169
[12,] 0.5015544 0.5029210 0.5042876 0.5056543
[13,] 0.1663651 0.1672414 0.1681177 0.1689940
[14,] 0.3331590 0.3341498 0.3351406 0.3361314
[15,] 0.1667938 0.1669083 0.1670229 0.1671374

> all(apply(A2, 1, Negate(is.unsorted)))
[1] TRUE
```

---

## Previous Answer

I guess you need some artificial interventions before sampling in a really "random" manner. Here is an example you can try

```
f <- function(C, nr) {
  res <- matrix(nrow = nr, ncol = C)
  res[1, ] <- sort(runif(C, 0, 1))
  for (k in 2:nr) {
    d <- diff(res[k - 1, ])
    v <- c(runif(1, 0, d[1]), d)
    res[k, ] <- cumsum(v - runif(1, 0, v[1]))
  }
  res
}
```

such that

```
> (A1 <- f(3, 3))
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.3800352 0.7774452 0.9919061
[2,] 0.1579321 0.5128165 0.6847518
[3,] 0.0979778 0.4387943 0.5966617

> all(t(apply(A1, 1, sort)) == A1)
[1] TRUE

> (A2 <- D %*% A1)
          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 0.2221031 0.26462868 0.30715428
[2,] 0.2820574 0.33865089 0.39524441
[3,] 0.0599543 0.07402221 0.08809012

> all(t(apply(A2, 1, sort)) == A2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you for your great idea! As discussed above, it is not necessary that the elements of A2 are distributed uniformly random. However, for C = 4 and increasing nr, the deviations between the stacked vectors in A2 become negligibly small which is suboptimal for my application. Maybe, this can't be avoided. Nevertheless, I will wait for a few days so there is still the chance that someone comes up with a different approach.

Answer (score 4):

Not a complete answer, but too long for a comment.

The goal as I understand it is to sample n vectors v<sub>1</sub>,
v<sub>2</sub>, …, v<sub>n</sub> ∈ (0, 1)<sup>d</sup> having sorted
entries such that, for all 1 ≤ i < j ≤ n, the vector v<sub>i</sub> −
v<sub>j</sub> has sorted entries.

Define the difference map Δ : **R**<sup>d</sup> → **R**<sup>d−1</sup> as

> (x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, …, x<sub>d</sub>) ↦ (x<sub>2</sub> −
> x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>3</sub> − x<sub>2</sub>, …, x<sub>d</sub> −
> x<sub>d−1</sub>).

A vector x ∈ **R**<sup>d</sup> is sorted if and only if Δx ≥ 0. In
particular, the vector v<sub>i</sub> − v<sub>j</sub> is sorted if and
only if Δ(v<sub>i</sub> − v<sub>j</sub>) ≥ 0. Since Δ is linear, this
condition is equivalent to Δv<sub>i</sub> ≥ Δv<sub>j</sub>, or,
expanding the universal quantification and including the proposition
that v<sub>n</sub> is sorted,

> Δv<sub>1</sub> ≥ Δv<sub>2</sub> ≥ … ≥ Δv<sub>n</sub> ≥ 0.

Thomas’s (first) proposal is

- Sample a sorted vector v<sub>1</sub> ∈ (0, 1)<sup>d</sup> uniformly
  at random (i.e., draw a random vector and sort it, since the
  degenerate cases are theoretically measure zero).
- For i from 2 to n, sample y<sub>i</sub> ∈ (0,
  (Δv<sub>i−1</sub>)<sub>1</sub>) × (0,
  (Δv<sub>i−1</sub>)<sub>2</sub>) × … × (0,
  (Δv<sub>i−1</sub>)<sub>d−1</sub>) uniformly at random, then sample
  v<sub>i</sub> ∈ (0, 1)<sup>d</sup> such that Δv<sub>i</sub> =
  y<sub>i</sub> uniformly at random (i.e., sample the first element
  from the appropriate range and compute the cumulative sums).

I’ve said uniformly at random a lot, but **the overall result is not
uniform random.** The entries of Δv<sub>n</sub> are disproportionately
likely to be small compared to brute force rejection sampling.

I suspect that it would be an improvement to sample, independently for
each j ∈ {1, 2, …, d}, uniform random (y<sub>n</sub>)<sub>j</sub> ≤
(y<sub>n−1</sub>)<sub>j</sub> ≤ … ≤ (y<sub>2</sub>)<sub>j</sub> ≤
(Δv<sub>1</sub>)<sub>j</sub>. But this is still not right, since
(intuitively) the more we shrink the differences, the more options we
have for the first elements.

---

I can’t seem to find a nice way to sample v<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>2</sub>,
…, v<sub>n</sub> uniformly at random. I did find a way to sample
Δv<sub>1</sub>, Δv<sub>2</sub>, …, Δv<sub>n</sub>, by grabbing n(d−1) +
1 exponentially distributed random values, normalizing out the extra
degree of freedom, and computing row and column cumulative sums
(cf. sampling from the Dirichlet distribution). Since you don’t care
about the sampler being uniform, we can just sample uniformly from the
v<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>2</sub>, …, v<sub>n</sub> that yield those deltas.
In (probably bad) R:

```
C <- 4
nvec <- 20
x <- rexp(nvec * (C - 1))
x <- x/(sum(x) + rexp(1))
A1 <- matrix(0, nvec, C)
A1[1:nvec, 2:C] <- matrix(x, nvec, C - 1)
A1 <- apply(A1, 2, cumsum)
A1 <- apply(A1, 2, rev)
A1 <- t(apply(A1, 1, cumsum))
A1 <- A1 + (1 - A1[1:nvec, C]) * runif(nvec)
```

Comment: nice analysis, +1! Yes, you are right, I didn't limit myself within `uniform` distribution (since I didn't see a hard request from OP's question) but just come up with an idea for constructing a matrix (or a pile of vectors if reading the matrix by rows) with somewhat "randomness"